# How many levels are there for the tanks game in Wii Play?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-play

I have researched how many levels there are in the tanks game in Wii Play and I found answers that had varying numbers. Some websites said 110 and others said just 20. How many levels are there in the tanks game in Wii Play?

Answer (score 3):

If you play the game the first time, there are only 20 Levels. In order to see all 100 levels you have to complete the first 20 levels once. From then on the game will continue after level 20. After that there are a total of 100 levels.

As far as I know the game **always** ends at level 20 when you play in Multiplayer mode - but I'm not 100% sure of that!

Comment: Yes, multiplayer always ends at level 20